# How to retrieve full node in a schema property: node

Tags: gentics-mesh

This is a slice of the schema I'm creating, lets say Schema A.

```
...
{
         "name":"topicList",
         "type":"list",
         "label":"topicList",
         "required":false,
         "listType":"node",
         "allow":[
            "topic"
         ],
         "elasticsearch":{
            "type":"nested"
         }
}
...
```

When I retrieve an object of schema A, topic property is an array of {"uuid": "string"} objects.

Is there a possibility to get the full object(otherwise I need to make an extra query to get metadata from those objects).

I know microschema can do this but the objects that I want to store are objects that are inside Topic Schema.

BR

Answer (score 0):

To fetch references to other nodes within one request use GraphQL.

https://getmesh.io/docs/graphql/#_loading_referenced_fields_of_a_node
https://getmesh.io/docs/api/#project__graphql__post

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://$MESH_HOST:$MESH_PORT/api/v2/$PROJECT_NAME/graphql/ \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":"YOUR_QUERY_HERE"}'
```